# Subquery returned more than 1 value error when using a cte

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to update the QTOTALNETWORTH field if QTOTALNETWORTH < (see the WHERE clause for all the fields).  When I use the below query I get the 'Subquery returned more than 1 value...' error.  I JOIN the cte to the ContactsQPROFILE by the primary key.

Where am I going wrong in this query?  Any help is appreciated.  I am using MSSQL.

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT ContactsQPROFILE,
                ( QVALUEOFHOME + QVALUEOFOTHERRE
                  + QRETIREMENTACCT + QLIQUIDASSTINPE + QBUSINESS
                  + QLIFEINSHUSTERM + QLIFEINSHUSPERM
                  + QLIFEINSWIFETER + QLIFEINSWIFEPER ) - QLIABILITIES AS TOTALNETWORTH
         FROM   ContactsQPROFILE
         WHERE  ( ( QVALUEOFHOME + QVALUEOFOTHERRE
                    + QRETIREMENTACCT + QLIQUIDASSTINPE + QBUSINESS
                    + QLIFEINSHUSTERM + QLIFEINSHUSPERM
                    + QLIFEINSWIFETER + QLIFEINSWIFEPER ) - QLIABILITIES > QTOTALNETWORTH )
                AND ( ( QVALUEOFHOME + QVALUEOFOTHERRE
                        + QRETIREMENTACCT + QLIQUIDASSTINPE + QBUSINESS
                        + QLIFEINSHUSTERM + QLIFEINSHUSPERM
                        + QLIFEINSWIFETER + QLIFEINSWIFEPER ) > 0.00 ))
UPDATE cqp
SET    cqp.QTOTALNETWORTH = cte.TOTALNETWORTH
FROM   ContactsQPROFILE cqp
       JOIN cte
         ON cte.ContactsQPROFILE = cqp.ContactsQPROFILE
```

Comment: Have you checked that the CTE only returns 1 result? And that combining it with the join also still is a one to one set? Otherwise the update statement won't now what value it needs to save in the ContactsProfile.

Comment: Probably the error is coming from a trigger on ContactsQPROFILE. There are no scalar subqueries in the code shown.

Comment: Guessing that the `JOIN` returns a one to many relationship? Why are you not using a (`PERSISTED`) Computed column? This would seem a better idea, as the data won't stagnant.

Comment: Yes.  I used the following query.  For each row that needs to be updated only one row is returned.      After the cte I use SELECT cte.*, cqp.* FROM ContactsQPROFILE cqp
 JOIN cte ON cte.ContactsQPROFILE = cqp.ContactsQPROFILE

Answer (score 1):

I think you can directly update the table:

```
UPDATE cqp
SET cqp.QTOTALNETWORTH = (QVALUEOFHOME + QVALUEOFOTHERRE + QRETIREMENTACCT + QLIQUIDASSTINPE + QBUSINESS + QLIFEINSHUSTERM + QLIFEINSHUSPERM + QLIFEINSWIFETER + QLIFEINSWIFEPER) - QLIABILITIES
FROM ContactsQPROFILE cqp
WHERE ((QVALUEOFHOME + QVALUEOFOTHERRE + QRETIREMENTACCT + QLIQUIDASSTINPE + QBUSINESS + QLIFEINSHUSTERM + QLIFEINSHUSPERM + QLIFEINSWIFETER + QLIFEINSWIFEPER) - QLIABILITIES 
    > QTOTALNETWORTH)
    AND   ((QVALUEOFHOME + QVALUEOFOTHERRE + QRETIREMENTACCT + QLIQUIDASSTINPE + QBUSINESS + QLIFEINSHUSTERM + QLIFEINSHUSPERM + QLIFEINSWIFETER + QLIFEINSWIFEPER) > 0.00)
```

Comment: I originally tried this and get the same error.  This is what lead me to use the cte thinking that would do it.  I tried your query and got the same error.

Comment: There is no subquery in his UPDATE query.

Comment: @NicVerAZ - you are correct but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @martinSmith I do see a trigger for this table.  I need to look into the trigger and see if this is causing the problem.

Comment: Ah the trigger would probably be causing this alert.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a CTE in this case because you are updating ContactsQPROFILE based on conditions internal to ContactsQPROFILE using columns only from ContactsQPROFILE.

That said, run the declarative part of the CTE alone and see if it generates duplicates for some reason.

Comment: I have run the cte part alone and get 8 unique rows that need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error due to the trigger.  As soon as I disabled it I was able to run the UPDATE query without using CTE.  I then enabled the trigger.

Comment: SO FIX THE TRIGGER! Don't just leave it for someone else to do.